# How to update the local cached credentials of AD user when DC is not reachable?

Tags: windows, active-directory, credential-providers

I am building a custom credential provider. In that I want to provide the option of Self Service Password Reset (SSPR) to users.

The SSPR works fine when the the DC is reachable from the user machine. But if the DC is not reachable (like if user is remote and and can not connect to DC on login screen) and user wants to do SSPR, how can I update the local cached credentials of the user? Updating of password in DC is taken care of.

I found some tools already providing this functionality. One example is [SSPR](https://specopssoft.com/product/specops-password-reset/?utm_source=helpnet&utm_medium=article&utm_campaign=remote%20reset%202020#) from specopssoft.

Is there any windows API which allows to reset/update the local cached credential of AD user?

Comment: Were you able to solve it?